# Adding dll via nuget to a framework 4.6.2 project results in the dotnetcore dll being used

Tags: c#

I have a C# solution that contains one project that targets .NET Framework 4 and Windows 8 (profile net40+win8).

I have another project that targets .net core. The `project.json` file for that contains:

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "dependencies": {
    "NETStandard.Library": "1.6.0"
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "netstandard1.6": {
      "imports": "dnxcore50"
    }
  },
  "buildOptions": {
    "define": [ "CORE" ]
  }
}
```

And the .xproj file contains:

```
<TargetFrameworkIdentifier>.NETCoreApp</TargetFrameworkIdentifier>
<TargetFrameworkVersion>v1.0</TargetFrameworkVersion>
```

I'm building the nuget package with `nuget.exe pack` specifying the `.csproj` file and by adding the following lines to the `.nuspec` file:

```
<files>
  <file src="..\SuccincT.Core\bin\Release\netstandard1.6\SuccincT.Core.deps.json" target="lib\dotnet\SuccincT.Core.deps.json" />
  <file src="..\SuccincT.Core\bin\Release\netstandard1.6\SuccincT.Core.dll" target="lib\dotnet\SuccincT.Core.dll" />
  <file src="..\SuccincT.Core\bin\Release\netstandard1.6\SuccincT.Core.pdb" target="lib\dotnet\SuccincT.Core.pdb" />
</files>
```

so that the dotnetcore dll is included too.

If I then inspect the resultant `.nupkg` file with the NuGet Package Explorer, I have the structure:

```
lib
    dotnet (.NETPlatform,Version=v5.0)
        SuccincT.Core.deps.json
        SuccincT.Core.dll
        SuccincT.Core.pdb
    portable40-net40+win8
        SuccincT.dll
```

So (to my untrained eye), that all looks good (I think the `.NETPlatform,Version=v5.0`, though deprecated, is due to the package explorer app being old and not understanding the newer .NET Standard notation).

However, I then created another project targeting the .NET Framework 4.6.2 and added a reference to SuccincT via the `.nupkg` file. When I look at the references, the SuccincT.Core.dll file appears. So it's taken the dotnetcore version. Even more strangely, this then compiles just fine, but dies with an error about not being able to find `System.Runtime` v4.1, when this new project is run.

Does anyone have any idea what is going on here? Why does it pick up the wrong dll? How does it compile, even though it is using a dll targeted at dotnetcore in a framework project? And, most importantly, how do I fix this?